# Query Python dataclass object by key like I can in nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a nested dictionary:

```
D = {'ID_1': {'name': 'Julie', 'age' : 19}, 'ID_2': {'name': 'Andre', 'age': 25}}
```

And I can retrieve an individual dictionary:

```
D['ID_2']
```

I would like to rather use dataclasses.
I can create a dataclass:

```
@dataclass
class User:
    name: str
    age: int
```

and then instantiate each ID:

```
ID_1 = User('Julie', 19)
ID_2 = User('Andre', 25)
```

But I would like to store all objects in one object and be able to query for a particular ID, just like I can when using dictionaries.

Comment: So store those instances in a dictionary, instead of assigning them to separate variables; what's the problem? You're changing the _inner_ dictionaries to dataclasses, but can still use the _outer_ dictionary just the same.

Comment: True I could use the outer dictionary just the same, but is there a way to do this using only dataclasses? Or would you recommend storing all of the objects as the values in a dictionary?

Comment: The outer dictionary is not a candidate for replacement with a (meaningful) dataclass. All it does is map strings to user information.

Comment: What do you mean _"only dataclasses"_? You mean have a dataclass-of-dataclasses? What's the point of that? Again, what's the _problem_ you're trying to solve?

Comment: `D = {'ID_1': User('Julie', 19), ...}`.

Comment: Yeah maybe a nested dataclass? I have read about the benefits of dataclasses, so I thought I would try to use them to store such information instead of dictionaries. I guess if you suggest, I will keep the outer dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's possible that the outer keys in the `dict` object might be dynamically populated (i.e. you could add an `ID_3` field later, and you don't want the code to break) - I would suggest using a custom outer class, and a nested dataclass `Person` for this particular task , as shown below.

> Note I would add a helper `from_dict` class method to make this a bit easier, rather than going through the constructor or `__init__` method.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


class MyClass:

    # not needed, but useful for type hinting purposes
    ID_1: 'Person'
    ID_2: 'Person'

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d: dict):
        o = cls()
        for k, v in d.items():
            setattr(o, k, Person(**v))

        return o

    def __repr__(self):
        fields = ', '.join(f'{k}={v!r}' for k, v in self.__dict__.items())
        return f'{self.__class__.__qualname__}({fields})'


@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int


data = {'ID_1': {'name': 'Julie', 'age': 19}, 'ID_2': {'name': 'Andre', 'age': 25}}
c = MyClass.from_dict(data)
print(c)

print(c.ID_1.name)  # Julie
print(c.ID_2.age)   # 25
```

Output:

```py
MyClass(ID_1=Person(name='Julie', age=19), ID_2=Person(name='Andre', age=25))
Julie
25
```

### Dot Access Dict

Another option which requires less boilerplate code, could be to use my helper library [`dotwiz`](https://dotwiz.readthedocs.io/), which enables dot or attribute-access for `dict` objects.

> Note: this example requires `pip install dotwiz`.

```py
import typing

from dotwiz import DotWiz


# define an alias
MyClass = DotWiz


if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:  # only runs for static type checkers

    class MyClass(DotWiz):
        # not needed, but useful for type hinting purposes
        ID_1: 'Person'
        ID_2: 'Person'

    # This is a stub class, only for type hinting purposes; it wouldn't
    # work if you wanted to define or use methods on the class.
    class Person:
        name: str
        age: int


data = {'ID_1': {'name': 'Julie', 'age': 19}, 'ID_2': {'name': 'Andre', 'age': 25}}
c = MyClass(data)
print(c)

print(c.ID_1.name)  # Julie
print(c.ID_2.age)   # 25
```

Out:

```py
✫(ID_1=✫(name='Julie', age=19), ID_2=✫(name='Andre', age=25))
Julie
25
```

> *Full disclaimer:* I am the creator and maintainer of this library.

Comment: Just wondering, any reason for the dv on the answer? I thought this provided a welcome solution to the OP's issue, more or less.